# How does Vcenter manage vsan

Tags: linux, vmware

I am a new one in the **vmware** environment, and i want to know what's the difference between **Vcenter** and **VSAN** cluster ? and how does **vcenter** host **vsan** cluster since **vsan** is already a cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

Think of the vCenter Server as a management layer. That management layer can control all aspects of a vSphere environments.

Clusters are created and maintained through vCenter. Without vCenter, clusters cannot exist. From that point, vSAN is a feature of a cluster. Meaning that you have to edit the configuration of a cluster to enable vSAN.

While I understand the VMware documentation calls it "vSAN Clusters", they are really "vSAN enabled Clusters"